# Numpy: TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, numpy, random

Given that i have a dataset as below:

```
dict = {
    "No": list(range(1,9)),
    "Pro":  [0.6703557312252965, 0.20395256916996046, 0.0782608695652174, 0.03241106719367589, 0.009486166007905139, 0.0031620553359683794, 0.0015810276679841897, 0.0007905138339920949]
}

dt = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

And i need to generate a number from "`NO`" column based on "`Pro`" column:

```
noList = dt["No"].tolist()
pro = dt["Pro"].tolist()
print("NoList", noList, " Pro: ", pro)
randomPolypNo = np.random.choice(noList, pro)
```

But, it complains with:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

What is the problem?

Comment: From the [docs](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html): parameter 2 is `size`, not the weights list. Try: `np.random.choice(dt["No"].tolist(), 1, p=dt["Pro"].tolist())`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to specify that pro is your probability distribution.

```
randomPolypNo = np.random.choice(noList, p=pro)
```

As is, it's interpreting pro as the size of the desired sample, which needs to be an int.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the arguments. Did you mean "Pro" as the probabilities? You can solve it by this.

```
randomPolypNo = np.random.choice(a=noList, p=pro)
```